# I like to change the font style in Acronym

Tags: acronyms

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[AWGN]
\acro{MRC}{Maximal Ratio Combining} 
\acro{QoS }{Quality of Service}
\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output} 
\acro{RF }{Radio Frequency} 
\acro{TAS }{Transmit Antenna Selection}
\acro{VAA}{Virtual Antenna Array} 
\acro{ASER}{Average Symbol Error Rate} 
\acrodef{SC}[SC]{Selection Combining} 
\acro{CSI }{Channel State Information} 
\acro{AF  }{Amplify and Forward}
\acro{SNR}{Signal-to-Noise Ratio} 
\acro{CDF }{Cumulative Distribution Function} 
\acro{PDF }{Probability Distribution Function} 
\acro{MGF }{Moment Generating Function}
\acro{AWGN}{Additive White Gaussian Noise}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

I like to have the font face and font size same in acronym 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\normalfont #1}`. Note that there is also `\acffont` and `\acfsfont` for corresponding versions. For more details, refer to the `acronym` manual page 2, section 2.2.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\acsfont}[1]{\normalfont #1}  %% use anything instead of \normalfont.
\begin{document}

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}[AWGN]
\acro{MRC}{Maximal Ratio Combining}
\acro{QoS }{Quality of Service}
\acro{MIMO}{Multiple Input Multiple Output}
\acro{RF }{Radio Frequency}
\acro{TAS }{Transmit Antenna Selection}
\acro{VAA}{Virtual Antenna Array}
\acro{ASER}{Average Symbol Error Rate}
\acrodef{SC}[SC]{Selection Combining}
\acro{CSI }{Channel State Information}
\acro{AF  }{Amplify and Forward}
\acro{SNR}{Signal-to-Noise Ratio}
\acro{CDF }{Cumulative Distribution Function}
\acro{PDF }{Probability Distribution Function}
\acro{MGF }{Moment Generating Function}
\acro{AWGN}{Additive White Gaussian Noise}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

[image]